# How to find P tag which has no siblings in it using Beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Some `<p></p>` tags has `<img>` tag and `<h4>` tag, but I want just those `<p>` tag which has no siblings tags in it just contents.

```
 <p> <img src="any url"/> </p>     <p> hello world </p>
```

I want `<p>` tag which has no `<img>` tag using beautiful soup

Comment: could you give an example... or the URL for us to understand what you mean??

Comment: What is the html hierarchy? It would be better if you could edit and add the tags.

Comment: @K163897 Muhammad Nafees did any of the answers posted below help solve your problem? If so, you may mark the one that you wish to, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This will get all the text in `<p>` elements but won't get it from any of the child elements in the `<p>`. Recursive needs to be equal false otherwise it will look into the child elements. I've added in another test case for you to show this: `<p><h4>Heading</h4></p>`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = "<p> <img src='any url'/> </p>   <p><h4>Heading</h4></p>  <p> hello world </p>"

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for element in soup.findAll('p'):
    print("".join(element.findAll(text=True, recursive=False)))
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution to get all `p` tags with no child tags.

```
import bs4
html="""<p> <img src="any url"/> </p>     <p> hello world </p>"""
soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")

def has_no_tag_children(tag):
    if  type(tag) is bs4.element.Tag: #check if tag
        if tag.name =='p': #check if it is p tag
            if  bs4.element.Tag not in [type(child) for child in tag.children]: # check if has any tag children
                return True
    return False

kids=soup.find_all(has_no_tag_children)
print(kids)
```

Output

```
[<p> hello world </p>]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming BeautifulSoup 4.7+, you should be able to do this:

```py
import bs4
html="""<p> <img src="any url"/> </p>     <p> hello world </p>"""
soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")

kids=soup.select("p:not(:has(*))")
print(kids)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = """
<p> <img src="any url"/> </p>     <p> hello world </p>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt)

for node in soup.findAll('p'):
    print(' '.join(node.findAll(text=True, recursive = False)))
```

OUTPUT:

> hello world